# Java swing keyPressed not working

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, java-2d, keyevent

I'm making Arkanoid game in Java Swing. When I run my game `KeyEvent` not working.

Why is the game not detecting key events?

Main class in my program make a frame (`JFrame`). Also I have `Manage` class which managing all classes from my game.

This is the code: `Player` class is class of paddle in my game.

```
//imports

public class Player extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener
{

    private int x, y, width, height;
    private Timer timer;
    private int fps = 60;
    private int delay = 1000/fps;

    public Player(int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        //setFocusable(true);
        addKeyListener(this);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        timer = new Timer(delay, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        timer.start();

        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        switch (e.getKeyCode())
        {
            case KeyEvent.VK_A:
                if (x <= 0) {
                    x = 0;
                } else {
                    x -= 3;
                }
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_D:
                if (x >= 600) {
                    x = 600;
                } else {
                    x += 3;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { }


}
```

Comment: use a debugger to find out what is happening

Comment: My guess is that you have not added the keyListener properly. You have added to the player(implements keyListener) object but you must be missing parts to you puzzle. Try to uncomment setFocusable.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a question. "Not working" is not a question.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) For Swing, we typically use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than the lower level `KeyListener`.

Comment: *"I have Main class which make frame"* Well don't include it in a comment (where it cannot be read). Instead [edit] the question and include it in an MCVE as I suggested 12 hours ago, so people trying to help do not have to make guesses or expend any effort to get an example of the failing code on-screen.

Answer (score -1):

The main problem with that code was that the custom painted component was neither focusable nor focused (so could not receive key events).

This code fixes those problems as well as a couple more (check code comments for details).

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Player extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    private int x, y, width, height;
    private final Timer timer;
    private final int fps = 60;
    private final int delay = 1000 / fps;

    public Player(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        addKeyListener(this);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        timer = new Timer(delay, this);
        timer.start();
        // a component must be focusable to get key events!
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //timer.start(); // Timer should already be started!

        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    // correct method for custom painting a JComponent is paintComponent!
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // call the super method to ensure previous paints are erased!
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    // a custom painted component should suggest a size to be used by the
    // layout manager
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(400,100);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_A:
                if (x <= 0) {
                    x = 0;
                } else {
                    x -= 3;
                }
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_D:
                if (x >= 600) {
                    x = 600;
                } else {
                    x += 3;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

            Player player = new Player(2, 2, 5, 20);
            f.setContentPane(player);
            f.pack();
            f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

            f.setVisible(true);
            // a component must be focused to detect key events!
            player.requestFocusInWindow(); 
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have Main class which make frame

Comment: `import javax.swing.*;


public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Manage manage = new Manage();

        frame.setBounds(300, 50, 700, 600);
        frame.setTitle("Arkanoid");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(manage);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}`